# How an SPI Should Evolve When Adding New Behavior

Tags: java, api-design

This is an SPI design question. I currently have the following Interface:

```
interface IService {
    void init();
    void add(AddArgs args);
    void get(GetArgs args);
    void close();
}
```

And now there's a new behavior that should be added: `void delete(DeleteArgs args)`

So my question is: how to introduce this functionality? Is it a new separate interface? Or should it be extending the one above?

In other words, this (1):

```
interface IDeletableService {
   void delete(DeleteArgs args)
}
```

versus (2):

```
interface IDeletableService extends IService {
   void delete(DeleteArgs args)
}
```

Or is there a new design that I'm not aware of.

Please note that "ideally" a deletableService is "currently" a Service. But this shouldn't mean that the second choice (2) is preferred. I'm rather asking about a good API design that is maintainable.

Answer (score 4):

Since Java 8, there are `default` methods, so you can add methods to interfaces without breaking existing code, e.g.

```java
interface IService {
    void init();
    void add(AddArgs args);
    void get(GetArgs args);
    void close();
    default boolean supportsDelete() {
        return false;
    }
    void delete(DeleteArgs args) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

As a general rule, if there’s an operation that can fail due to not being supported in general, there should be a way to check whether the operation is supported without the need to actually try the operation. (The Collection API violates this principle)

Implementations must care to implement both methods.

Alternatively, you could generalize the concept of optional operations:

```java
enum Operation {
  ADD, GET, DELETE
}

interface IService {
    void init();
    void add(AddArgs args);
    void get(GetArgs args);
    void close();
    default Set<Operation> supportedOperations() {
        return EnumSet.of(ADD, GET); // fallback for old implementors
    }
    void delete(DeleteArgs args) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

which is expandable to even more new operations.

By the way, when your service has a `close()` method, you should consider extending [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html).

Comment: This is the best answer so far. 1) I wouldn't bother with supportsDelete() or you'll end up with many supportsXXX and doXXX pairs of methods as your API grows. 2) I also wouldn't implement AutoCloseable since its close() method forces your API to throw Exception, even if it doesn't make sense for your case.

Comment: @DeleTaylor no, `AutoCloseable` doesn’t force you to declare an exception. You can always override a method and declare less (or more specific) exceptions. See for example [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) which extends `AutoCloseable` but has a `close()` method not declaring any exceptions. Likewise `java.io.Closeable` extends `AutoCloseable` but its `close()` method narrows `Exception` down to `IOException` while `java.sql.Statement`’s `close()` method narrows `Exception` down to `SQLException`.

Comment: Good point about `AutoCloseable`. I retract point #2.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer via the means of **SOLID** principles to make this easy for you.

If you think that `IService` is going to be modified every time when a new functionality/behaviour is introduced. So, in that case, you should avoid making the interface too big.

Instead, you split them into separate interfaces based on the behaviour by following the **Interface Segregation Principle**.

**Note:** Also, you are making sure that the class implements the required behaviour/methods from an interface only via this principle thereby, removing the overhead of providing a default implementation for an unused behaviour in the implementation class.

This will make sure that you are following **SOLID** principles correctly and a good **API** design too.

Your code should look something like this:

**IInitService:**

```
interface IinitService {
    void init();
}
```

**ICloseService:**

```
interface ICloseService {
   void close();
}
```

**IAddService:**

```
interface IAddService {
   void add(AddArgs args);
}
```

**IGetService:**

```
interface IGetService {
   void get(GetArgs args);
}
```

**IDeleteService:**

```
interface IDeleteService {
   void delete(DeleteArgs args);
}
```

Now, let's say you want to create class which will be responsible to provide `add` functionality only.

```
public class AddServiceImpl implements IAddService, IInitService, ICloseService {

     @Override
     public void init() {
        //.....
     }

     @Override
     public void add(AddArgs args) {
        //.....
     }

     @Override
     public void close() {
        //.....
     }

}
```

This is quite maintainable.